# NPM vs WEBPACK comparison

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-4

What is the difference between **webpack** and **npm**? Should I be using them both? What are the pros and cons of using *webpack* and *npm*? Which one more preferred? Is it necessary to learn *webpack* when you know *npm*?

Answer (score 11):

npm and Webpack are two completely different tools that do completely different things.

npm is the default package manager for JavaScript. It is a huge registry of packages for all kind of JS development. It is highly unlikely that you will not need it.

Webpack is a module bundler. It is mostly used to manage JavaScript codebases, most often for usage in the browser, and requires Node.js to use.

To answer question : Webpack (and all its associated plugins) is on npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack). So, you need to know what npm is and how to use it to use Webpack. But you might not need Webpack. There are other solutions to bundle browser JS code, like Rollup or Parcel.